# Copying binary data with memcpy in c

Tags: c, string, binary, char, memcpy

I have the following problem when using memcpy:

Suppose that an hexadecimal data must be copied in binary, e.g.: 203800000E820006, then apply the following instruction:

```
unsigned char buffer[8];
memcpy(buffer,"\x20\x38\x00\x00\x0E\x82\x00\x06",8);
```

However, when I write the data in binary, it only prints the 2 first bytes in binary, because \x00 is interpreted as a string terminator. How to avoid or fix this in order to represent the 16-char string in a 8-char binary format?

Comment: What do you mean by "it only appears"?! Appears where? Also, why the "+1"? This is 8 bytes of data, right?

Comment: Your code is fine, and your `buffer` array should end up containing precisely the 8 bytes you desire.  Why do you say "it only appears the 2 first bytes"?  Were you doing `printf("%s", buffer)` or something?  That makes sense, because `%s` expects a null-terminated string, so it stopped when it saw one.  But the rest of the data was there (it just didn't get printed).

Comment: @TinoReyna It's not a string. Please don't call it a string. If you print it, you have to use code that knows how to print 8 bytes of binary data. Are you using such code?

Comment: I think your problem is you're being unclear what you mean about the string containing your hexadecimal data.  If you want the string `"203800000E820006"`, then write it that way.  (Of course, that's 16 bytes, not 8.)  If you want an 8-byte array containing the values 0x20, 0x38, ..., 0x00, 0x06, that's what your code is successfully creating, but that 8-byte array is not a string, you can not `printf` it using `%s`, you can not copy it using `strcpy`, etc.

Comment: If I wanted an 8-byte array containing those bytes, I would not bother with `memcpy`, I would just write `unsigned char buffer[] = {0x20, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x82, 0x00, 0x06};`.

Comment: @TinoReyna: I said I don't think you should be formatting it as a string (because it's not a string), but I did not suggest using an integer array.  An array of `unsigned char` is fine.  You can store 8-byte integers into the cells of an array of `unsigned char` just fine.

Comment: Perhaps you're confused about the relationship between integers, characters, and strings in C.  Characters are just little integers with values based on your machine's character set (e.g. 'A' is 65 on an ASCII machine).  Strings are just arrays of characters.

Comment: For example, try this code: `int main() { char str[] = {0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x00}; printf("%s\n", str); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buffer you have is not a string.  You can't treat it like one by passing it to functions expecting a string such as `strcat`, `strcpy`, `strcmp`, or the `%s` format specifier of `printf`.

You have an array of characters, so print them as such:

```
int i;
for (i=0;i<sizeof(buffer);i++) {
    printf("%02hhX ", buffer[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```